# Dynamics CRM WEB API- Select field from entity reference

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am trying to select a field from another CRM entity by using an expand with my odata query.

Query string: `studios$?Select=studioid,studioname,titleid&$Expand=`

Title id is a field in custom entity called title. How do I write an expand clause to expand title and select titleid?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

first you can refer to this [article from docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2015/developers-guide/gg309461(v=crm.7)#expand) explaining in detail the $expand feature, however for simplicity is followed by the relation name with targeted entity then the fields you want to select in parentheses

for ex. `$expand={relation_name}($select=filed1,field2)`

which might be something like this
`$expand=new_new_entity1_new_entity2($select=new_name,createdon)`

**Notice:** the values you get from expand relation will be actually navigation URL to actual data, so you don't expect [new_name,createdon] from new_entity2 to be retrieved, what you will get will be a url to OData those values and for that you might below helping function 1 will do it for you

Also you can use [XRM Rest Builder](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/jasonlattimersblog/archive/2016/12/09/crm-rest-builder-v2-5-0-0) that's an amazing solution when you install on the crm you will find it's button in solutions view. that solution is a tool helps you to design your OData query with nice GUI so that you don't need to write and refine your OData query which is faster and easier.

**Helping function 1**

`

```
function OdataExpand(expandUrl) {
    var result = null;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", expandUrl, false);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                result = results;
            } else {
                console.log("OdataExpand Error : ");
                console.log(this);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
    return result;
}
```

`

but if you want to get all the data with one call and maybe you want to expand to more than one entity i recommend that you use Fetch XML simply design the fetch you need using advanced find tool to extract the fetchXML then pass it to Helping Function 2 that should return the full data but be aware that max fetch length in this approach is limited to 2,048 characters [Max Length for GET Request].

**Helping Function 2**
`

```
function ExecuteFetchXMLQuery(dataSet, fetchQuery) {
    var encodedFetchXML = encodeURIComponent(fetchQuery);
    var result;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.0/" + dataSet + "?fetchXml=" + encodedFetchXML, false);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue\"");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200 || (this.status >= 200 && this.status <= 206)) {
                console.log("Success Executing Fetch");
                var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                result = results;
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error Executing Fetch");
                console.log(this);
                console.log(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
    return result;}
```

`

Comment: Thanks guys for your knowledge and advise. I tried the studios?$select=studioid,studioname,titleid&$expand=titleid($select=titleid,name), still getting a 400. The CRM Rest Builder- is that a solution that needs to be installed? How do I run this? Sorry if its a newbie kind of question. Thanks!!

Comment: @RaviShastri that’s a managed solution you can import within CRM. Check your entity & field names, they should look like new_studio & new_studioid

Comment: @RaviShastri pls upvote/accept answers if they helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
studios?$select=studioid,studioname,titleid&$expand=titleid($select=titleid,name)
```

Also it’s recommended to use [CRM REST Builder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) to compose & test CRM web api queries.

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/query-data-web-api#retrieve-related-entities-by-expanding-navigation-properties)

Note: Check your entity & field names, they should look like new_studio & new_studioid